# How to collect same value into JSON object?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have multiple inputs with following format:

```
<input type='text' class='i_skema_qty' id='skema_1_bbg' value='1000' />
<input type='text' class='i_skema_qty' id='skema_1_acg' value='700' />
<input type='text' class='i_skema_qty' id='skema_2_bbg' value='1200' />
<input type='text' class='i_skema_qty' id='skema_3_bbg' value='1700' />
<input type='text' class='i_skema_qty' id='skema_2_acg' value='1540' />
<input type='text' class='i_skema_qty' id='skema_1_spm' value='900' />
<input type='text' class='i_skema_qty' id='skema_2_spm' value='300' />


//CONTAINER
<input type='text' class='i_grand_total' id='total_bbg' />
<input type='text' class='i_grand_total' id='total_acg' />
<input type='text' class='i_grand_total' id='total_spm' />
```

I'd to collect all of those input value and group them into a json object. The format should be:

```
[{"unit_kerja": "bbg","total": "3900"},{"unit_kerja": "acg","total": "2240"},{"unit_kerja": "spm","total": "1200"}]
```

`unit_kerja` in the array is dynamic based on the inputs. However it always more than zero. Then, the array should be inserted to the `i_grand_total` container which is matching with the count of the array.

This is my current script which is i'm stuck here:

```
var grand_total = 0;
    $('.i_skema_qty').each(function(i){
        var _this_ttl    = $(this);

        var total_item   = parseFloat( _this_ttl.val().replace(',', '') );

        var arr_uk_skema = _this_ttl.attr('id').split('_');
        var uk_skema     = arr_uk_skema[2];                

        grand_total      = grand_total + total_item;
        alert(uk_skema +":"+ grand_total);          
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd reduce into an object indexed by the `unit_kerja`, whose values are the array objects, eg `{"unit_kerja": "bbg","total": "3900"}`. Iterate over every `i_skema_qty`, create the object in the accumulator if it doesn't exist yet, and add to the `total`. Then, get the object's values to turn it back into an array, and map to turn `total` into a string rather than a number:

```js
const grouped = [...$('.i_skema_qty')]
  .reduce((a, input) => {
    const key = input.id.match(/[a-z]+$/)[0];
    if (!a[key]) {
      a[key] = { unit_kerja: key, total: 0 };
    }
    a[key].total += Number(input.value);
    return a;
  }, {});
const output = Object.values(grouped)
  .map(obj => ({ ...obj, total: String(obj.total) }));
console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='i_skema_qty' id='skema_1_bbg' value='1000' />
<input type='text' class='i_skema_qty' id='skema_1_acg' value='700' />
<input type='text' class='i_skema_qty' id='skema_2_bbg' value='1200' />
<input type='text' class='i_skema_qty' id='skema_3_bbg' value='1700' />
<input type='text' class='i_skema_qty' id='skema_2_acg' value='1540' />
<input type='text' class='i_skema_qty' id='skema_1_spm' value='900' />
<input type='text' class='i_skema_qty' id='skema_2_spm' value='300' />
```

Comment: Hi.. @CertainPerformance thank you for your answer. However, i'm not familiar with your code. I'm using old version of jquery. I hope you can modified  my current code based from your code. Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: The only jQuery I'm using here is `$('.i_skema_qty')` - everything else is just built-in Javascript, don't worry, any version of jQuery will work just fine (you could even remove the jQuery from the script entirely very easily, just replace `$` with `querySelectorAll`)